# How to make a solid using sections using OPENCASCADE

Tags: surface, opencascade

I create several sections using point data, and finally create a CAD module using OPENCASCADE to create a solid.
Until now, the work of creating a section using points has been completed.
I would like to know how to create a solid using these sections.
Anyone can help?

```
std::vector<iFan::vector3D>::const_iterator posS;
for (posS = pointData.begin(); posS != pointData.end(); ++posS)
{
    //curve
    Handle(Geom_BSplineCurve) bspline = COCC_Geometry::GenBSplineCurve((*posS), 0.00001, true);
    TopoDS_Edge out_shape = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge(bspline);

    TopoDS_Wire Wc = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire(out_shape);
    
    TopoDS_Face F = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace(gp_Pln(gp::ZOX()), Wc);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use `BRepOffsetAPI_MakePipe` for that: https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_b_rep_offset_a_p_i___make_pipe.html

I have only used it to combine wires as profiles to create shells, but the documentation seems to imply that you can also sweep faces to create solids out of it. The only restriction is that the profiles may not be solids themselves.

You will have to use `BRepOffsetAPI_MakePipe` between two sections each and then combine all the solids to one resulting solid.